# Blender crashing when saving file

Tags: osx

Blender 2.83 now crashes when I try to save a new file. I'm using Mac OS 10.14.6 and when I try to save a new file and select any directory, I get the spinning beachball. Force quitting is my only option. I've turned off all add-ons; same result. I've also downloaded Blender 2.90.1 and get the same result. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Might be broken user preferences, issues with the graphics driver or unsupported hardware. Try to go through [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports/173685#173685) and report it on the bug tracker if non of the steps give you an answer why it doesn't work.